# Is it okay to fix my old questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, old-questions

I want to go through my old questions to fix the content and formatting (*autonecroediting?*).  Most of them are badly phrased and annoying to read, but they might be useful to someone down the line.

The issue is that edits bump questions back to the front page, and I don't want it to look like I'm rep-farming.  Will I get any flak for editing my old, inactive questions?

Comment: If you [google autonecroediting](http://www.google.com/search?q=autonecroediting), this question is the only result!  Its been years since I last saw a near empty google search!  You may well be the first person in the world to use that term.  +1 just for that !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is nothing wrong if you want to improve your (and others') questions, I'd say it's even appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

No that's entirely fine IMO. I recently retagged all my approx 70 C++0x questions (apart from one or two) to C++11 and earned some rep by that, but nobody did mind. And I don't see any reason why anyone would mind.

Same for your matter.