# Trouble in reviewing Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, support, review, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beta review indicator on canned comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144222/beta-review-indicator-on-canned-comments)

A few days ago I surpassed 2K reputation on SO, so I started reviewing *Low Quality Posts*. While reviewing such posts, I got some negative replies as comments, like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903110/how-can-i-make-this-css-popup-work/3903353#comment16072845_3903353) and [this comment (not to me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054072/calculating-angular-rate#comment16051713_4054330).

Mostly, they say *Are you commenting on very old post?* or *Why did not you comment on another answer, which is also a low quality post?*

What reply should reviewers give the commenters?

Comment: Don't worry to much and keep reviewing, there is still a lot to do.

Comment: Maybe throw 'em a link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113672/is-it-okay-to-fix-my-old-questions or just ignore them. Or...don't leave a comment, if it really bugs you. If you don't think there's anything they can (or reasonably would) do to improve the post it might be better off just quietly swept away.

Comment: @Gamecat & BenBrocka. Whatever happen, I will keep reviewing.

Comment: You may tell them about the review system, and that the site automatically flagged their post as low-quality. Maybe that will convince them to improve the post, and/or start reviewing other posts too.