# I can't change the tags for a question if the question fails validation

Tags: discussion, edits, jsfiddle

I tried to change the tags on [Get The Current Domain Name With Javascript (Not the path, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401897/get-the-current-domain-name-with-javascript-not-the-path-etc/11401923#11401923)

When I tried to save my change, I was chastised that the question contained a jsfiddle with no code. Since validation failed, I couldn't save my change.

I shouldn't be held responsible for someone else's problematic question if all I'm doing is changing a tag.

Comment: If you fix one thing, fix all things.

Comment: same question I asked a few days ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203204/whats-the-policy-for-editing-old-questions-which-do-not-comply-with-newer-restr I agree that old posts should be fixed if you encounter one.

Comment: I added an answer to the dupe question. @Bart, I don't think that's a practical requirement. Changing a tag takes *way* less time than constructing a useful code sample. As a result, I did neither. I don't think SO is better off for that.

Comment: All you had to do is copy the content from the fiddle into the post.

Comment: I copied the JSFiddle content into the question, now @Dancrumb feel free to go ahead with the tag editing.